# Sublimetext highlighting of braces

Tags: editors, braces, sublime-text, syntax-highlighting

In SublimeText 3, the syntax highlighting for latex documents in math mode has the following (unexpected?) behavior. Consider the following:

`\{sometext\}` versus
`\{ sometext\}`.

The syntax highlighting on `\{` differs between the two; in the first case it does not match the syntax highlighting on `\}`.

Is there a good reason that I don't know for this? If not, can I (easily) change it? I guess my preference would be to have both of them match the highlighting on `\{` in the first case, but having the open and close match one another is a minimum.

I've tried looking at the syntax highlighting definition file for latex but the file is long and hard for me to read; if someone can even just point me to the right line in that file, that would be much appreciated.

Here's a screenshot. The color scheme is espresso libre. I see now that the problem occurs in some but not all color schemes (e.g. also in pastels on dark). It also seems to occur only with `$` and not within `\[ \]`.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @DG' added. I've uninstalled all plugins to see whether that was the problem, but I have the same issue. Maybe you were in a color scheme that doesn't have the issue? if you still can't replicate, I'll try a fresh install.

Comment: Using your code I found the same problem with ST2, ST3, Atom and Textmate 2. Maybe it's a bug in the TM bundle they are all based on.